Network utilization maxed out during backup. Is it bad in itself?
We have a cluster of two Oracle DBs.
Monitoring software agent is installed on both of the machines and overnight, when backups are happening, we get warnings that network interface utilisation on the servers is above 90% - I'm sure it gets maxed out.

Is this an issue or do you, experienced DBAs, allow the DB servers to occasionally max out the network interface bandwidth? If not, what are the known issues this could cause?
Thank you in advance!

While the network throughput is maxed out, or close to, other activity will see higher latency, slower throughput, or both. How much of a problem this is for you depends on your desired system responses during the time.
If the increase in latency experienced by apps talking to the database is significant enough that end-users might notice, and feel it enough to care, then you can mitigate this by limiting bandwidth to the backup destination to make sure it takes no more than, say, 85% of the available throughput. This will of course make the backups take longer to complete, obviously, which might be more of a concern.
Note that the backup process is likely to only be a single stream, it won't saturate the link as badly as you will see due to, for example, P2P sharing traffic. To assess if you should be concerned or not, arrange a simple test of the applications during the time the backups are happening, or to be more thorough run a deeper load test then & at another time and compare the results.

Thank you for the detailed and to-the-point answer!
